# How does size work within objects Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Midway through making my program I realise there are some discrepancies between the height / width properties of objects.

For example in my document here, the main green frame has a width of 640 whereas the buttons are only a size of 3 yet they appear so much larger. How exactly is width and height calculated (is it always pixels)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY3PI.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `width` and `height` attributes don't always refer to pixels. For some widgets, the width and height is in characters. For example, `Label(root, text="Hello", width=10) will make a widget that is wide enough to hold 10 average sized characters in the default font.

Just about any widget that has text will measure width and height in characters (`Text`, `Label`, `Button`, etc). Widgets that do not have text as part of their normal appearance (`Frame`, `Canvas`, etc) are measured in pixels.

For some, the value of `width` and `height` depends on other options. For example, in a `Button` or `Label`, if the widget sets the `image` attribute then the values will be in pixels, and if the `image` attribute is not set then the values will be in characters.

The documentation for each widget will say what the `width` and `height` represents.

Answer (score -2):

Ya, Height and Width is measured in pixels

Comment: Not always. Height and width for some widgets is based on a number of characters.